# Can't assign to function call, yet code seems correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making a VERY simple calculator, because I was bored, but for some reason it errors out with 'Can't assign to function call'.
This is the code:

```
type=input("Please select a method.\n\n1.) Addition\n2.) Subtraction\n3.) Multiplication\n4.) Division\n\n")
if type == "1":
    int(number1)=input("First number?")
    int(number2)=input("Second number?")
    answer=number1+number2
    print ("The answer is " +answer +".")
if type == "2":
    int(number1)=input("First number?")
    int(number2)=input("Second number?")
    answer=number1-number2
    print ("The answer is " +answer +".")
if type == "3":
    int(number1)=input("First number?")
    int(number2)=input("Second number?")
    answer=number1*number2
    print ("The answer is " +answer +".")
if type == "4":
    int(number1)=input("First number?")
    int(number2)=input("Second number?")
    answer=number1/number2
    print ("The answer is " +answer +".")
else:
    print("Pick a number from 1-4")
```

I feel like this is very obvious and I'm just being an idiot.

Comment: YOu need to call `int` on the `input` calls not the variable names

Comment: Isn't `type` a reserved word, and thus should be avoided as a variable name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the input string to int, not the variable it is getting assigned to:

```
if type == "1":
    number1=int(input("First number?"))
    number2=int(input("Second number?"))
    answer=number1+number2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting your variables to `int` at the wrong time. You need to cast the input given to you as an integer, rather than cast the variable to an integer before a string value is given to you.

All instances similar to `int(number1)=input("First number?")` need to be changed to `number1 = int(input("First number?"))`.

This is called [precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html).